# Get local time in 24hr format

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

I know this is a rather *under-level* question, if you may, but I'm having some trouble looking for code that I can put in my Windows forms. I just have three mere requirements:

- I need the local time, which is EDT.
- I also need the time in 24-hour format so it's easier to read.
- Where to put the code in my Windows forms?

Comment: Just because it's not clear, are you using Managed C++? Your reference to Winforms doesn't make sense, otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* localtime example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

 return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/

Comment: Thanks for the code Jeremy, but, how do I put it in my WinForm?

Comment: I just ran the program... I specified no dates!!! You also got the code off of that website below your answer, which I already saw.

Comment: Sorry you didn't see, someone took the date part off my question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged your question with 'winforms' I'm assuming you're running on the .NET Framework.  If so, I suggest starting here:

[Coding Best Practices Using DateTime in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx)

... and also checking the documentation on DateTIme formatting here:

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the references Duncan, I'll keep it in mind when I use the DateTime thing. :)

Comment: No assumption needed, the `c++-cli` tag makes use of .NET blindingly obvious.